# Microsoft Visual C++ Runtime Library - Runtime Error - How to suppress the error

Tags: c#, c++, .net, wpf, matlab

It looks like a duplicate, but believe I checked other answers, nothing worked.

My application started crashing while closing the application with below error. It was working properly few days back, some recent changes is causing the issue. And one this starts on a machine, even though I replace with previous working `DLL`, still the issue comes.

```
Microsoft Visual C++ Runtime Library
Runtime Error!

Program:C:\DigiMic\...
```

This application has requested the Runtime to terminate it in an unusual way...
This pop-up comes for 1 second with OK button, then automatically closes. The main problem is it happens while shutting down my application.
My Application: It is a `WPF`, `C# application` which uses `Matlab` used business DLL for few functionality. The application works fine while using the Matlab used DLL and its function, only crashes while exiting the WPF.

I tried to Wrap the `App.Current.ShutDown` with `try..catch`... but the it never hits `catch` or`finally` block. Then I also tried `AppDomain.Current.UnHandledException += new...`, it still does not hit the function on exception.

The other problem is, I am not able to see the complete path of the exe that causes this exception.

Question:

1. Is there a way, I can suppress this error?
2. Where is this error gets logged in windows?I tried to look into Event Viewer, but nothing is there.
3. Is there any workaround? Since it's software delivery time for the product. :(

Comment: Run the application under the debugger.  When the error occurs, just go into the debug menu and choose "Break" or "Break All".  Then you have the call stack that led to that dialog box showing up.  Also, you never want to suppress errors -- that error could be caused by a memory corruption bug that could show up in other parts of the program.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie : As I mentioned the exception occurs while closing the application and extremely limited time to act on the exception, it does not give opportunity to choose `BreakAll`. The application closes with in 1 sec.

Comment: That dialog is part of the Visual C++ runtime, and you have the source code to this function.  I don't know exactly where that dialog source is located, but it's there.  If you put a breakpoint at that point in the code, the program will stop.

Comment: Also, I would suggest building a debug version of the the DLL.  Then MSVCRTD.DLL will come into play, and this is where you will more than likely be successful in narrowing down the issue.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I tried running the ProcessExplorer, msvcp80.dll and msvcp90.dll are being used by my application (not sure which component). and only these two dlls uses the MS Visual C++ Runtime. I suspect any of these DLLs causing the issue. Can you guess anything? And the dialog is not an application side, it is a generic Windows Dialog.

Comment: The "Runtime Error" message in my old version of Visual Studio is in `crt0msg.c`.  It really isn't a generic dialog -- you should have the source code to it right there, i.e. it isn't a trade secret.  If you can find this file in your VS installation, this is more than likely the source code I'm referring to.  If you can get a breakpoint to hit that line, maybe you will be successful in finding what the issue is.  However, you must make sure that you have loaded the symbols for the particular runtime DLL.